# PHP Iterate Through Associative Array and Get Specific Values

Tags: php, associative-array, loops

I have the following associative array:

```
<? $group_array;
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Array
(
[user_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 594
        [1] => 597
    )

[user_first] => Array
    (
        [0] => John
        [1] => Jane
    )

[user_last] => Array
    (
        [0] => Smith
        [1] => Jones
    )

)
```

My question is: How can I iterate through the array and output the specific values by it's name?

For instance, something like:

```
<?php
   foreach ($group_array as $key => $value) {
       print($key['user_id']);
       print($key['user_first']);
       // etc...
   }
```

But this doesn't appear to work.  Any help on this would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($group_array['user_id'] as $key => $value) {
  print($value); // user id
  print($group_array['user_first'][$key]);
  print($group_array['user_last'][$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate through the array to call the keys by their names

```
echo $group_array['user_id'][0];
// Result: 594
```

If you wanted to iterate through the values, you could do:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($group_array['user_id']);$i++) {
    echo $group_array['user_id'][$i];
    echo $group_array['user_first'][$i];
    echo $group_array['user_last'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Crayon Violent answer is right, but i think your array is not structured well, for easy access and usage i'd recommend something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 594
            [user_first] => John
            [user_last] => Smith
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 597
            [user_first] => Jane
            [user_last] => Jones
        )
)
```

For an easy access like this :

```
foreach($group_array as $person) {
    print($person['user_id']);
    print($person['user_first']);
    print($person['user_last']);
}
```